# JQuery Textarea background color not working in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a website, in which I have image and above image I am having textarea, the text area style is this

```
<textarea rows="1" style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; resize: none; overflow: hidden; font-family: lucidablackletter; font-size: 27pt; border: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 400px; text-align: center; background-image: inherit; background-size: inherit; background-attachment: inherit; background-origin: inherit; background-clip: inherit; background-color: transparent; line-height: 66.66666666666666px; background-position: inherit inherit; background-repeat: inherit inherit;bottom: 0;">add text here</textarea>
```

and its placed just above the image, so It has same background color as of image, I have option of setting background color of textarea, which I am doing with JQuery,I can also Clear the color to the original one(ie same as of image) which I set.
This is working fine on Chrome and FF, but on IE its setting the background color of textarea to white

this is how i am clearing

```
function ElementBgClear(cssClass) {    
    var element = jQuery(cssClass);
    if (element != null && element != undefined && element.length > 0) {
        element.attr("style", "");

        element.find("textarea").css("background", "");

        jQuery(jQuery(currentEditField).children()[0]).css("background-color", "inherit");
        SelectTextColor(null, jQuery("#frontSideBgColorsTable"));
    }
```

I have tried

element.find("textarea").css("backgroundColor", "");

and

```
    element.find("textarea").css("background", "transparent");
```

but no luck :(

How can I set Bg color of textarea to transparent in IE

Comment: IE7 does not support inherit for any properties besides direction and visibility.

Comment: I also want to add that no matter if you use background-color, backgroundColor, jQuery is supposed to understand both just the same. So if one doesn't work, the other won't and vice versa. However "background" will probably not work with Jquery. I think I remember reading from the Jquery documentation that it doesn't suppoer compound properties such as "background" and "border".

Comment: @Ariane seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dA7Mw/2/ Maybe it didn't in an older version

Comment: I have checked on IE9 as well and its not working even there

Comment: @KevinB I guess you're right! I never truly tested it.

Answer (score 0):

in ie8 doesnt work transparent for background property

You can use

```
background: url('blank.gif')
```

when blank.gif is an image 1px x 1px and transparent

Comment: Doesn't Jquery not work with compound properties? I think it should be "background-image".

Comment: @Ariane in ie8 `background` works perfect, ie8 auto-translate from `background` to `background-image`

Comment: (removed -- see comments to the above question; apparently I was wrong)

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi are you sure you have the image 'blank.gif' in the path from the url?

Comment: @Michael I can't use Blank.gif, as I have to set the same color as intially it was